# Can you put h:outputLink inside h:commandButton?

Tags: jsf, richfaces

I need a button that takes the user back to a certain page and for that purpose I've put a h:outputLink inside a h:commandButton as seen below:

```
  <h:commandButton styleClass="richButtonLogout">
   <h:outputLink value="/pages/somePage.xhtml">
 SomePage
</h:outputLink>
```

I was expecting the button to get me to the specified page when clicked, but instead I see a separate button and a separate link in the browser. So, the link is outside of the button. The button won't do anything , while the link works normally.
A similar approach works fine with html, so I thought it would be ok.

Comment: Can't be done in regular HTML, so can't be done in JSF. Why not simply use your button's action?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you cannot put an `outputLink` inside a `commandButton`. These are seperate components not associated with or dependant on each other.

If you want a button to function as a link you can use the `h:button` JSF component in combination with the `outcome` attribute like so,

```
<h:button outcome="..."/>
```

Note though that while it indeed works, the JSF `button` component uses JavaScript to achieve this navigation - so it's not an ordinary link as you would expect. Because these are navigation outcomes (not links) - one advantage with this method is that you can use static outcomes and dynamically define your navigation rules in `faces-config.xml`.

Obviously, to achieve a plain old link, you could also just use an ordinary `<a href="...">` with appropriate button styling to achieve the same end result.

Comment: And using plain html instead of wrongly using (abusing) JSF components is a very valid thing to do.